# GAE running tasks frozen

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, app-engine-flexible

I have been working with GAE for a long time now, but since a couple of weeks ago some of my queues get frozen because the running tasks are stuck at the max concurrent parameter.

For example, I have a queue with 10 as the max concurrent tasks. And the running tasks number has been 10 for a while, not letting any of the new tasks to run and filling a lot over time. If I use run now manually they work just fine, but even if I empty the queue like this the running tasks is still 10.

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly. You are using the queue.yaml file used to manage task queues, and you are using the max_concurrent_requests parameter.

This Parameter sets the maximum number of tasks that can be executed simultaneously from a specified queue. You can read about this here [1].

Recently, GCP has release a now Beta API  called Cloud Tasks, which could be helpful to you. You can find the overview here [2]. Also, here is a quickstart for app engine queues [3] very useful to start using the Google Cloud Tasks API.

Please tell me if this documentation has helped you with your task problems.

Regards.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/queueref

[2]https://cloud.google.com/tasks/

[3]https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/quickstart-appengine